# How to know which case happens when nonblocking recv returns 0?

Tags: c, sockets, recv

I have simple TCP server that runs with non-blocking sockets.

Quote from manpage of recv;

> When a stream socket peer has performed an orderly shutdown, the return value will be 0 (the traditional "end-of-file" return).

> The value 0 may also be returned if the requested number of bytes to receive from a stream socket was 0.

When socket is readable I read it with this code:

```
uint8_t buf[2048];
ssize_t rlen;
while(1){
    rlen = recv(fd, buf, sizeof(buf), 0);
    if(rlen < 0){
        /* some error came, let's close socket... */
    }
    else if(rlen == 0){
        /* is there no bytes to read? do we need break; in here? */
        /* is socket closed by peer? do we need to close socket? */
    }
    /* some code that process buf and rlen... */
}
```

How we can know which case happens when `recv` returns 0?

Comment: The code with `rlen == 0` will never be reached in the first place since your while conditions assumes `rlen != 0`

Comment: Apart from that the documentation is quite clear: either the connection was closed or you did not request any bytes to recv, i.e.  `sizeof(buf) == 0`

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sorry my bad lemme edit

Comment: The requested number of bytes in your code is 2048, which is nonzero. So the second case can't happen.

Comment: On error -1 is retrned and errno is set. For some specific errno values it means that no data needs to be read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `recv` returns 0 it means that the socket has been gracefully closed by the other peer and can be closed from your side as well. When no data is present in socket, -1 is returned and [`errno`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) is      set to `EAGAIN` / `ETIMEDOUT` and the socket hasn't to be closed.

Finally, when -1 is returned and `errno` is set to a value different from `EWOULDBLOCK`or `EAGAIN` the socket has to be closed, because some unrecoverable error occurred.
For non-blocking sockets it means that no data is immediately available when `recv` is called. For blocking sockets) it means tgat no data is available even after the timeout (`SO_RCVTIMEO`) previously set with `setsockopt()` expired.

---

As you correctly quoted in your last edit, 0 can be returned from `recv` also if the requested size is 0.

> How we can know which case happens when recv returns 0?

Just test the provided recv size (in this case it is the size of a constant array, so it doesn't make much sense; but in case it is a variable coming from elsewhere...):

```
bufSize = sizeof(buf);

/* further code that, who knows, might affect bufSize */

rlen = read(fd, buf, bufSize);
if(rlen < 0){
    if (errno != ETIMEDOUT && errno != EWOLUDBLOCK)
    {
        /* some error came, let's close socket... */
    }
}
else if(rlen == 0){
     if (bufSize != 0)
    {
        /* Close socket */
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't errno `ETIMEDOUT` means we need to close socket too? I suppose `EWOULDBLOCK` means `there is no any data right now except recv with blocking`

Comment: @fakwjdkawjdawk You are right. I wrongly had in mind a proprietary implementation I worked with, that used to return ETIMEDOUT in a blocking socket in case the timeout (`SO_RCVTIMEO`)
   previously set with `setsockopt ()` expired. I'll edit my answer

Comment: by the way you forgot to change code part in your answer

Comment: `sizeof` never returns 0.

Comment: @rici it's just example. also it's possible to get sizeof 0 with zero length array extension. gcc supports it; `int a[0]; printf("%u\n", sizeof(a));`

Comment: I found that when there is no data available on socket and socket is non-block then also it returns 0 with recv() call and the connection is still open. Manual do not clarify behavior about non-block sockets.